# PHP - SimpleXML Adding a new Parent

Tags: php, simplexml, parent-child

I have an XML file (example below) and it is sitting somewhere on the net. When I import it using SimpleXML like so `$sXML = @simplexml_load_file( $url );`, the contents of the files are converted in the simple XMl objects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<title>Test</title>
<description>Test Description</description>
<item id="500">
<title>Item Title</title>
<description>Item Description</description>
</item>
<item id="501">
<title>Item Title</title>
<description>Item Description</description>
</item>
```

I would like to add a new set of parents. One at root level and the other that contains "item" so that it looks like the XML file below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
<title>Test</title>
<description>Test Description</description>
<content>
<item id="500">
<title>Item Title</title>
<description>Item Description</description>
</item>
<item id="501">
<title>Item Title</title>
<description>Item Description</description>
</item>
</content>
</data>
```

How is this possible using SimpleXML or any other way?

Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Your input XML is invalid. The mandatory root element (whatever tag name it has) is missing. SimpleXML fails to parse it.

Comment: It's interesting to note that because the OP used the mute operator `@`, the error was suppressed. The mute operator should pretty much never be used, and especially not during development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the input XML given as example is invalid. It is mandatory to have a single root node. That said, here is a possible solution:

```
$sXML = simplexml_load_file($url);

$nonItems = '';
$items = '';
foreach ($sXML as $child) {
    if ($child->getName() == 'item') {
        $items .= $child->asXML();
    } else {
        $nonItems .= $child->asXML();
    }
}
$xml = sprintf('<?xml version="1.0"?><data>%s<content>%s</content></data>',
        $nonItems, $items);
// echo simplexml_load_string($xml)->asXML();
```